# Date range question

Tags: php

If I have 2 dates, **21/05/2010** and **23/05/2010**, how can I find out if **22/05/2006 7:16 AM** exists in between them?

I am using the following code to calculate the min/max date and will then SELECT ALL records in the table that are clear to update them.

```
    $today = date('l');

    if($today == 'Wednesday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('0 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+6 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Thursday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+5 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Friday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-2 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+4 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Saturday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-3 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Sunday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-4 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Monday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-5 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Tuesday'){
        $min = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-6 days'));
        $max = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('0 days'));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Create a DateTime::diff between *21/05/2010* and *22/05/2006 7:16 AM*, as well as a DateTime::diff between  *23/05/2010* and *22/05/2006 7:16 AM*.

Then check that the first DateTime::diff is `> 0`, and the second is `< 0`

*Update* : used Datetime::createFromFormat, which is a php5.3 method

*Update2* : Tested code sample. Produces expected output.

```
<?php
$datetime_lower = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '21/05/2010');
$datetime_upper = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/05/2010');
$datetime_compare = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', '22/05/2006 7:16 AM');

var_dump($datetime_lower < $datetime_compare);
var_dump($datetime_upper > $datetime_compare);

if ($datetime_lower < $datetime_compare && $datetime_upper > $datetime_compare) {
    echo " + date is between";
} else {
    echo " date is not between";
}
```

Also, there is a procedural [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function

Comment: i get the following error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (15/12/2010) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character' in C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php:269 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php(269): DateTime->__construct('15/12/2010') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php on line 269"

Comment: i still get the error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (21/05/2010) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character' in C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php:269 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php(269): DateTime->__construct('21/05/2010') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\pay.php on line 269

Comment: Ah, yes. That is a problem with the format of the date being passed in. I made and update above, but if you do not have PHP5.3, you would need to format the date another way before entering it into DateTime().

Comment: oh it works now. so "if ($diff_lower > 0 && $diff_upper < 0)" is TRUE then the date in between and "if ($diff_lower > 0 && $diff_upper < 0)" is FALSE THEN the date is not between?

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime

```
 $date1 = strtotime($date1);
 $date2 = strtotime($date2);
 $datefind = strtotime($datefind);

 if ($datefind >= $date1 &&  $datefind <= $date2)
```

Comment: Partially true. But if you're just using strtotime() to parse dates quickly, just supply dates in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (YYYY-MM-DD) format, i.e. 2010-05-21 instead of 21/05/2010. I'd recommend using ISO 8601 in any case, as it's less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Explode your dates and use the parts in a mktime() to get their timestamp values. Then it's a simple matter of checking if your timestamp is larger or smaller than the others.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Pseudocode:

```
$parts= explode("/", "21/05/2010");
$timestamp1= mktime($parts[0], $parts[1], ...);

if($timestamp1 < $timestamp2...) {
    print "timestamp1 is older then timestamp2";
}
```